# Append two para side by side using shell,sed,awk

Tags: shell, awk, sed

Hello i have below raw output

## Chunk-1

```
Mod Ports Card Type                              Model              Serial No.
---+-----+--------------------------------------+------------------+-----------
1     8  Sup 8-E 10GE (SFP+), 1000BaseX (SFP)   WS-X45-SUP8-E      CAT1903LAEN
3    48  10/100/1000BaseT Premium POE E Series  WS-X4748-RJ45V+E   CAT1743L2JQ

M MAC addresses                    Hw  Fw           Sw               Status
--+--------------------------------+---+------------+----------------+---------
1 c08c.60ef.f340 to c08c.60ef.f347 1.2 15.1(1r)SG7  03.09.01.E.112   Ok
3 24e9.b335.bfd0 to 24e9.b335.bfff 1.3
```

## Chunk-2

```
Mod Ports Card Type                              Model              Serial No.
---+-----+--------------------------------------+------------------+-----------
1     8  Sup 8-E 10GE (SFP+), 1000BaseX (SFP)   WS-X45-SUP8-E      CAT1903LAEN
3    48  10/100/1000BaseT Premium POE E Series  WS-X4748-RJ45V+E   CAT1743L2JQ

M MAC addresses                    Hw  Fw           Sw               Status
--+--------------------------------+---+------------+----------------+---------
1 c08c.60ef.f340 to c08c.60ef.f347 1.2 15.1(1r)SG7  03.09.01.E.112   Ok
3 24e9.b335.bfd0 to 24e9.b335.bfff 1.3                               Ok
```

want to combine and create the single line. and append 
expected output

But if i do all at one time, all lines starting with 1 from chunk 2 will also get appended, along with lines from chunk-1.
So wanna process chunk-1 first, and then chunk-2.

Assume this as single line:

## Chunk-1 Output

```
1     8  Sup 8-E 10GE (SFP+), 1000BaseX (SFP)   WS-X45-SUP8-E      CAT1903LAEN 1 c08c.60ef.f340 to c08c.60ef.f347 1.2 15.1(1r)SG7  03.09.01.E.112   Ok
```

Another line:

```
3    48  10/100/1000BaseT Premium POE E Series  WS-X4748-RJ45V+E   CAT1743L2JQ 3 24e9.b335.bfd0 to 24e9.b335.bfff 1.3
```

Similar manner need chunk-2 output as well.

Comment: its in same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]/{a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1] FS $0 : $0} END{for(v in a)print a[v]}' file
```

Comment: if i have multiple chunk of this in the same file, but wanna process one at a time. what needs to be changed here?

Comment: @user1220402, What do you mean by "process one at a time" ? Post a sample input.

Comment: have edited my question it self, you can check there as its too long for comment.

Comment: @user1220402, You can do it like this : `for f in a1.txt a2.txt; do awk '...' $f $f.out; done`